# Azure DevOps environment with private EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, amazon-eks

I am currently using EKS private cluster with a public API server endpoint in order to use Azure DevOps environments(with Kubernetes service connection).

I have a requirement to make everything private in EKS.

Once EKS becomes private, it breaks everything in Azure DevOps as it is not able to reach the API server.

Any suggestion on how to communicate private kubernetes API server with azure devops would be appreciated.

Comment: Did the offered solutions help you?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to target the cluster for deployment, you need a self-hosted agent that has a network route to your cluster.

The other capabilities exposed by the environment feature of Azure DevOps (i.e. monitoring the state of the cluster via the environment view) will not work -- they require a public-facing Kubernetes API to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the additional cost, VPN can be used to establish connection to the private EKS cluster.